# Remote Access to PostGIS

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgis

For the last three/four months i've deployed PostGIS locally but now i've just been given a server to deploy PostGIS on and scale up my open source adventures. I've installed Postgres/gis and its working just fine on my Windows server, but how do I connect to it from my desktop pc (via QGIS). I've looked around for threads on 'Remote Access PostGIS on Windows Server' and variation of, but haven’t actually found anything concrete.

I get the gist that I have to edit the some of the Postgres config files to allow remote access, but the threads that do comment on doing this all offer difference solutions. Very confused!

Comment: This a pretty big issue and not directly related to GIS. Configuring an RDMS for remote access and all of the related authentication, authorization and security issues shouldn't be taken lightly. I suggest you at least get a book on the PostgreSQL administration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. It's built into the IP protocol used by PostgreSQL.

However, it partially depends on your network. Does your Windows Server have either a static IP or a DNS name (e.g., yourname.com)? If your server have a dynamic IP, try something like http://dyn.com/dns/. Furthermore, if your server is behind a firewall or router, you might need to use port forwarding to expose the PostgreSQL port (usually 5432) to outside traffic.

The PostgreSQL/PostGIS side of things is easier to set up. There are *tonnes* of resources out in the web to tell you how to enable remote connections to a PostgreSQL database (e.g. [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html)). Basically, you need to edit your `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files, and either restart and/or refresh your server.

To connect from QGIS, make a new connection with the DNS name or IP address in "Host". I frequently use QGIS to connect to remote servers.

Comment: I changed the the postgresql.conf and the pg_hba.conf and my server guy has said that the port 5432 on our router has been exposed and still i cant get a connection from QGIS to the remote Postgres. Any further ideas?

Comment: I can speak from experience that this could take a good while to setup, and I needed a server guy to help set it up too. Make sure you can first connect within your intranet from another computer, then try from outside your network to see if the port is correctly forwarded to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Take spacial attention to the

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

configuration in postgresql.conf.

By default it only allows local conections and you need to put the '*' to allows connection from any machine.

Comment: The listen_addresses tells PostgreSQL what IP address to listen on. Not what machines to accept connections from.

Comment: Yes, but double check it, if you only accept local connection no matter what you configure on ph_hba.conf you never connect remotelly.